# Vanishing files on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, azure, files

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 web server installed on an Azure virtual machine.
I am encountering a strange issue, where on seemingly random occasions files or directories are suddenly deleted without warning.

I am the only one with access to the vm. I tried looking at logs but found nothing which is relevant.

I have tons of other linux servers which I set up myself and none of them have ever had these issues.

Did anyone ever come across this issue with Ubuntu on Azure?
Is there anything I may be missing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
Reuben.

Comment: Which files - server (linux) files, web content, logs, other? Which directories? From where?

Comment: basically anything in /var/www, this is filled with web content. To my knowledge nothing else was effected.

Comment: If you didn't delete them, then someone else has access to the VM. Could be through access to the server due to security configuration. Could be through your web server (http) due to web server configuration vulnerability in CMS, etc. In any case, you are going to need to provide much more information.

Comment: ok, so this was my first thought however i could not find any clues within the logs. Also at certain times instead of the files being deleted, they are getting corrupt (with garbage text written all over, even in file names). Which logs would you start looking at?